# Phonegap build Failed Firebase Analytics

Tags: ios, firebase, cordova, phonegap-build

I have created the sample app with firebase analytics and GTM using phonegap build
It is working fine in android.

In IOS if i am using below pod for firebase and GTM, build failed with below error

```
<framework src="Firebase/Core" type="podspec" spec="~> 5.6"/> 
<framework src="GoogleTagManager" type="podspec" spec="~> 6.0"/>
```

> Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-firebase-analytics': Error: pod:
>   Command failed with exit code 1
>       at ChildProcess.whenDone (/private/project/cordova/node_modules/cordova-common/src/superspawn.js:169:23)
>       at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
>       at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:962:16)
>       at Socket.stream.socket.on (internal/child_process.js:381:11)
>       at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)
>       at Pipe._handle.close (net.js:611:12) pod: Command failed with exit code 1

In IOS if i am using below pod for firebase and GTM, build successful but We couldn't see any log in GA console but we can see log in Firebase console

```
<framework src="Firebase/Core" type="podspec" spec="~> 4.1"/> 
<framework src="GoogleTagManager" type="podspec" spec="~> 6.0"/>
```

Please Advice

Comment: I don't really know the phonegap integration or syntax, but suspect that the GoogleTagManager version should be 7.0 not 6.0.

Comment: any different between GoogleTagManager 6.0 and 7.0

Comment: Compatibility with Firebase 5.x versus Firebase 4.x

Comment: U mean GoogleTagManager 7.0 is compatible for 5.x and GoogleTagManager 6.0 is compatible for 4.x is right

Comment: I have tried this. Now i am getting in console

> GoogleTagManager warning: No default container found. Container needs to be added to a container folder and added to the target.

After create and move the GTM-XXXX.json file to container folder. I am getting below error

> GoogleTagManager info: Attempting to load saved version of container GTM-XXXXXX

Please advice